# Batch / Find And Edit specific location in TXT or XML file and replace it with random

Tags: batch-file, random, location, text-files, edit

i want to replace a text file which contain a password in a line to the same text file but random password

EXAMPLE:

```
01 username:admin
02 password:12345678
03 login
```

i want to let the batch file to locate the "12345678" and edit it with random 
8-digit numbers like this:

```
01 username:admin
02 password:72957823
03 login
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code you want us to help you to fix? Please note that this site does not provide a free code to order service; members help you to fix issues with your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming original file is named  **pass.txt**  this *displays* what the changed file might look like.

```
@echo off& setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%l in (pass.txt) do (
  set "l=%%l#$#"
  for /f "delims=" %%p in ("!l:*password:=!") do if not "!l!"=="%%p" (
    set /a "r=(!random!<<15|!random!)%%100000000+100000000"
    set "l=!l:%%p=!!r:~1!#$#"
  )
  echo !l:~,-3!
)
```

No comment on strength of new "random" password... that's another issue.